# iOS :trying to scraping a page on iOS inspite of sending all the same parameters the browser sends

Tags: ios, jsp, cookies, web-scraping, nsurlconnection

I'm trying scrape a page. This a jsp server. There is a guest login, so as soon as open the URL I'll be redirected to index page where i'll be logged in as guest and i'll get a cookie and everything works fine on a browser.

I want to do this on my iOS app. So here I'm hitting the index URL and getting the cookie ( along with other parameters which browser sends) in the request to the server to make further requests. I copied this from the chrome and copied it as curl.

```
GET URL HTTP/1.1
Host: HOST
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

But i'm able to get the response from the server by using this cookie, But i'm getting the response if I use the cookie from the browser. Can you please let me know what i'm missing.?

These are the parameters which i'm adding to request to simulate a browser request.

```
[request setValue:@"gzip,deflate,sdch" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
[request setValue:@"max-age=0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cache-Control"];
[request setValue:@"keep-alive" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];
[request setValue:@"en-US,en;q=0.8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Language"];
[request setValue:@"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/11B508" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
```

Comment: Where's the Java code? If you're building the HTTP request manually and then writing it...you probably did it wrong. Use a HTTP client library.

Comment: @developerwjk I don't have the access to java code. The requests on the browser works fine. But i'm sending same parameters on curl or iOS fails. is there any other parameter that will not show up on chrome console??